# What's the better approach in changing the model's property value in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance

Which approach is more preferrable when changing just a single value in model? Aesthetically-speaking and performance-wise.

Looks clean(albeit with the overhead of pushing the entire model again to the `View`):

```
ModelState.Remove("Name");
guestResponse.Name = "John";
return View(guestResponse);
```

Looks performant:

```
ModelState["Name"] = new ModelState { Value = new ValueProviderResult("Paul", null, null) };                
return View();
```

If changing the model state dictionary is performant and can do this...

```
ModelState["Name"] = "George";
```

...I will use that over the first code(with `Remove` and `return View(guestResponse)`), but unfortunately, ModelState need to be assigned with ModelState and ValueProviderResult.  It looks ugly to me.

Which one do you use when changing the model's property value(s) in controller?

Comment: I vote for readability over performance, granted I don't really think there will be any noticeable performance difference here. You don't really have to "push" something to the view again. You're giving the view a different object reference to look at, but the view still has to be rendered no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model properties are usually bound from the request values. So if I need to change a model value inside a controller action I simply call this action with the proper request string so that I don't have to do anything inside the controller. But to answer your question both approaches will perform well, it doesn't really matter which one you use.